# Hide a report item from print / export of an rdlc report

Tags: visual-studio-2008, rdlc, reportviewer2008

I have an RDLC with multiple tables and for each table, I have a toggle TextBox Item that hides the corresponding table from the report. It works perfectly, however, I don't want these text boxes to be visible in the printed/exported reports. They are really meant for disabling content in the report and not as content themselves. Is there a way to hide those toggle boxes from only Print Layout and exported versions of the report?

I looked at all of the properties of the report textbox and at the available expressions that I can use to toggle visibility, but I didn't find anything that I can use to hide the item. There is a DataElementOutput property that seems to be what I want, but I believe that it is only useful for XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late, but there are one solution. You can add a parameter to the report for handle control visibility and in the Print event, change the parameter value and then refresh the report (ReportViewer1.RefreshReport())

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using a simple visibility toggle. You can use the RenderFormat.IsInteractive variable to determine whether a report is shown in report viewer or is being exported. An [MSDN article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robertbruckner/2010/05/02/globalsrenderformat-aka-renderer-dependent-report-layout/) explains this about this global variable,

> Furthermore, a Boolean flag (=Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive)
>   determines whether a rendering extension is an interactive renderer,
>   i.e. not an export format. Preview (GDI/Winforms) and HTML viewing are
>   considered interactive renderers.

Set the visibility of the text box you want to hide in the export to the following expression

```cs
=NOT(Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive)
```

Refer to the following image (courtesy of [blog.hoegaerden.be](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2011/01/18/ssrs-hideshow-items-dependant-on-export-format/)) to know the values assigned to RenderFormat.IsInteractive
[image: RenderFormat.IsInteractive]

Answer (score 0):

You can do some hacks to try to accomplish that like:
- setting the text and border on your TextBox to be white so they are not vislble but still clickable
- make report bigger than print size (paper size) and move your textboxes out of the print area (they will be printed/exported but not on the same page like your tables)
- put your textboxes on top and design them to look like tabs which enable different views (I know, I know, this is not what you asked for :-) )

But the best way to solve this is to split your report in to several reports - for each table one report.

hope this helps!

cheers,

Pero